# Child View ignoring Parent Layout which holds Nested Layouts, but uses them instead

Tags: android, xml

I have a spinner which is in the parent layout, which holds the Spinner, and nested Relative layouts. The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to get the Spinner to align to this parent layout, even when I specify to align in parent, it still aligns to a nested view.

To clarify: My Spinner is being aligned to the top left of "relativeone", not "back_layout".

Any ideas?

Relevant XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/back_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:entries="@array/spinner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeone"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativetwo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Take Photo" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some minor changes to your properties to make it work.

Drop the center align from `back_layout`, drop the align left from the spinner, and add center in parent to `relativeone`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/back_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeone"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativetwo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Take Photo" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Tha above layout will give you this:

[image]

Comment: I had played around with changing back_layout to linear layout previously, however this time it appears to have done something different. It has now put the spinner beneath relativeone and to the left. (I have added layout_gravity="top|left" to spinner. I haven't moved spinner though, so Im again unsure as to why it has been drawn beneath rather than on top. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Anthaas I re-did my answer to use RelativeLayout, see if that works any better for you.

Comment: Ive decided that because of how the phone will be held during this activity, that having the button in the bottom left is actually more preferable. Thanks so much for your help!